# Why is my BETWEEN clause not working?

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with this query?
I followed the `BETWEEN` syntax found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm).

```
SELECT * from immunochemistry
WHERE release_date BETWEEN '01-01-2015' AND '12-31-2015';
```

Why do I still get the 2013 and 2020 in my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dates need to be in the format `'2015-01-01'` for MySQL. As per the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html).

Comment: You can output dates however you want, see here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp But in your query you need to write it in the format mysql expects, like I said in my answer.